# Looping over two-dimensional array containing objects in Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js

**The problem**

In Vue, I'm passing an array called issues. The array contains (at present) two objects, but can contain infinite amounts of objects. Every object then has another array named issues, nested inside of it.

The issue is that when I need to display the data, I find that I can't seem to reach the inner "issues" section of it.

I can loop through the first array like so:

`<tr v-for="issue in issues" track-by="id">`

But that only lets me see the first two objects. I then tried:

```
<tr v-for="issue in issues" track-by="id">
    <td>
        <div class="btn-table-align" v-for="issue_title in issue.issues">
            @{{ issue_title.title }}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Which lets me access the sub-elements, but doesn't generate enough rows. I then tried looping over it AGAIN, like so:

```
<div v-for="first in issues" track-by="id">
    <tr v-for="issue in first" track-by="id">
        <td>
            <div class="btn-table-align">
                @{{ issue.id }}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

But, alas - it generates no rows at all when I do that.

I'd basically need a way to run a "issue in issues", then another for the results and THEIR direct children. The only issue is - I can't figure out how to do it, and Vue won't respond to any of the above attempts! I find a severe lack of documentation on two-dimensional arrays in Vue as well, which has me confused further.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is it possible, or do I *need* to adjust the data sent to Vue differently?

To help, I shot an image of an example structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwEPU.png

Comment: the first code is correct. What do you mean by "doesn't generate enough rows"? What is your desired result?

Comment: try traking-by="$index" in the loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a typical 5am question, where I now realize that the data I'm passing makes no sense - it should be the other way around. The actual issues should be in the first array, and the subarray should contain affected servers.